# Error submitting form via JavaScript (.submit())

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have the following modal window on my page:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="BillsReceive" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Register new product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php 
        
        include 'BillsReceive.php';
        
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button id="submit-add-article-form" title="New Register" class="btn btn-success" onclick="fncSendForm();"> <i class="fa fa-plus">  </i>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The modal window has an include that contains a page with a "registration form" of accounts receivable. The form on the "BillsReceive.php" page is below:

```
<form action="../I_MVC/Controller/Registrations/InsertBillsReceive.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="BillsReceive" name="BillsReceive" >
<div class="container">

<br/>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> Code:</div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example" name="Code"> </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
   </div>
   
<br/>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> Usual Name:</div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example" name="UsualName"> </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
   </div>
   
<br/>
   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> Type:</div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example" name="Type"> </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
   </div>
   
 <br/>

</div>

</form>
```

Well then, the "Save Changes" button of the modal window calls a JavaScript function to send the page's form. Below is the javascript function that should submit the form:

```
function fncSendForm()

{
    
    document.getElementById("BillsReceive").submit();
    
}
```

But when calling the function in javascript, the following error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a
> function
>
> ```
> at fncSendForm (VM34 InsertBillsReceive.js:10)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM41 ShowBills.php:1113) fncSendForm @ InsertBillsReceive.js:10 onclick @ VM41 ShowBills.php:1113
> ```

Why is the submit function not submitting the form? The function is correct and the file is linked in the modal window page. Why didn't the function work?

Comment: It doesn't seem that this issue has anything to do with PHP, since you say that the include, which is the only PHP in here, works.

Comment: Your code should work, the problem lies within the fact that your submit button is not in the same file as the form itself or perhaps is loaded before the form and that might cause an issue - put a button inside or beside the form just for testing ... it should work. I didn't see any variables in the form so unless you are sending problematic characters thats the only thing I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are loading parts of your code in wrong order and or maybe they are not in the right file.

Your js function should be loaded after the form is created - the best is last!

when jamming it to one file your code works with no prob...

This works (note: I changed the action for the example):

```
<form action="./show.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="BillsReceive" name="BillsReceive" >
<div class="container">

<br/>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> Code:</div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example" name="Code"> </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
   </div>

<br/>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> Usual Name:</div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example" name="UsualName"> </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
   </div>

<br/>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> Type:</div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-xxl-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Default input" aria-label="default input example" name="Type"> </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 col-xxl-1"></div>
   </div>

 <br/>

</div>

</form>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="submit-add-article-form" title="New Register" class="btn btn-success" onclick="fncSendForm();"> <i class="fa fa-plus">  </i>Save Changes</button>
</div>


<script>

function fncSendForm()

{

    document.getElementById("BillsReceive").submit();

}
</script>
```

file show.php:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
```

output on show.php:

```
Array
(
    [Code] => 3243223
    [UsualName] => 43543646
    [Type] => 657576657
)
Array
(
)
```

I'm betting the include is located in the wrong place and is not running with the rest of the code...